# Prove that $\lim\limits_{r \to\infty} \int_1^{r-1} \int_1^{r-y} \frac{\sin x}{x^4+y^4} dx dy$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Prove that $\lim\limits_{r \to\infty} \int_1^{r-1} \int_1^{r-y} \frac{\sin x}{x^4+y^4} dx dy$ exists (and is finite).

I was able to show that $\int_1^{r-y} \frac{\sin x}{x^4+y^4}dxdy$ converges when $r\to\infty$, but that didn't help. I also tried to use the fact that 
$|\int_{1}^{r-1}\frac{\sin x}{x^4+y^4}dxdy|\leq \int_1^{r-1} \int_1^{r-y} \frac{dxdy}{x^4+y^4}$, but that doesn't say anything as far as I understand.

So I basically have no clue. Hint, please?

Comment: Bound everything by $$\int_1^\infty\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^4+y^4} dx dy$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:
The AM-GM inequality gives

$$x^4+y^4\ge 2x^2y^2$$

Comment: Gee... So simple. That worked. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure. -Mark